# How should I secure SignalR groups?

Tags: security, signalr

I have a set of server-side resources that have authorization rules. By way of example, the resource is of type "widget", and each widget has an access control list determining which users have access to the widget.

**Widget 1**

- User A
- User B

**Widget 2**

- User B
- User C

I have a SignalR hub for "widget", and there is a group for each widget, i.e. a group for widget 1 and a group for widget 2. The hub notifies when a property of the widget changes. So if widget 1 is changed, user a and user b would be notified, but not user c.

To complicate things just a little further, I want each user to be able to choose whether or not they receive notifications for a given widget. In other words, they will actively join and leave groups.

Setting aside authentication, what are the authorization security concerns I need to deal with?

I figure the act of joining a group would work like this:

```
class WidgetHub : Hub
{
    public Task ListenToWidget(string widgetId)
    {
        if (UserIsAuthorized(Context.User, widgetId)
        {
            return Groups.Add(Context.Connectionid, widgetId);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedWidgetException(widgetId);
        }
    }
}
```

And I'd need to override default behaviour on `BuildRejoiningGroups` in the hub pipeline, [per SignalR documentation](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#verify), something like this:

```
public class RejoingGroupPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    public override Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> 
        BuildRejoiningGroups(Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> 
        rejoiningGroups)
    {
        rejoiningGroups = (hb, request, listOfGroups) => 
        {
            List<string> allowedGroups = new List<string>();
            foreach (var group in listOfGroups)
            {
                if (UserIsAuthorized(request.User, group))
                {
                    allowedGroups.Add(group);
                }
            }
            return allowedGroups;
        };

        return rejoiningGroups;
    }
}
```

Is this the extent of requirements for ensuring authorization on groups?

I'm also a little confused by one statement in particular on the SignalR documentation [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#groupsecurity):

> **Do not use groups as a security mechanism**
>
> Groups are a convenient way of collecting related users, but they are
>   not a secure mechanism for limiting access to sensitive information.
>   This is especially true when users can automatically rejoin groups
>   during a reconnect. Instead, consider adding privileged users to a
>   role and limiting access to a hub method to only members of that role.
>   For an example of restricting access based on a role, see
>   Authentication and Authorization for SignalR Hubs. For an example of
>   checking user access to groups when reconnecting, see Working with
>   groups.

I can't tell if this applies to my described situation. I'm not really using groups as an authorization *mechanism*, rather, I'm using *other* mechanisms to secure groups. But then, "(groups) are not a secure mechanism for limiting access to sensitive information" makes it sound like I shouldn't be using groups in this way.

Comment: Hi,

I've the same scenario, wondering if you solved this and if you have any advice or know any other resources which may help.

TIA.

Comment: I am also faced with the same dilemma, security is a concern. If in doubt, retrieve "ConnectionId's" and send individually, rather than creating a "Group". Keen to find out, if you managed to implement a secure environment using groups?